# Check when finger enters ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

(I know that there are others like this, but bear with me because I have a special problem)

So I am developing a game called Dodge in which the user dodges `ImageViews` that come from the top of the screen to the bottom. What I am aiming to do is that when the user's finger enters the `ImageView`, run `endGame()`. I have already set it up to lose when you lift your finger.

The problem here is that you are starting the game by using an `ACTION_DOWN` event on a `TextView`, and when you lift your finger, you lose. The problem with this is that I cannot figure out how to run another `onTouch` inside the one already running from a finger drag.

My `TextView` `onClick()`

```
title3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int eventAction = event.getAction();

            switch (eventAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //On button down
                    startGame();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // finger leaves the button
                    endGame();
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` in conjunction with `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` and see if it that x, y coordinate falls within one of the falling pic's boundaries.

Comment: I get what your saying, but how does one go about seeing if it falls within the `ImageView`? I know for rectangles you can use `.contains(x,y)`, but I don't know the equivalent for `ImageViews`

Comment: Loop through your ImageViews and see if `imageView.getX() >= event.getX() && event.getX() <= (imageView.getX() + imageView.getWidth())` is true to determine if the X point is inside the image.  Do the same for Y and use height.

Comment: Using this solution has had some weird outcomes. I see exactly how this code should work, but when put into action, the second that you move the touch, it runs `endGame()`, but only sometimes. Otherwise, it allows the move, but when it intersects the `ImageView`, nothing happens. I've played around with it, but to no prevail. Any suggestions? @chris

Comment: I would throw in some `Log` debug statements and see where the issues are.  Make sure you have your switch statement breaks and check the movement x and y's along with your imageview x and y's.

Answer (score 0):

onTouch called Continuous when user touch the screen, and usually its enough
you must use getX and getY function to indicate finger location and do something
and use MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL when finger out of view

Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

**Action_Down** -- for the first pointer(finger) that touches the screen.This starts the gesture.

**Action_Pointer_Down** -- for the extra pointer(second finger) that enters the screen beyond the first.

**Action_Move** -- A change has happened during a press gesture

**Action_Pointer_Up** -- sent when a non primary pointer goes up.

**Action_Up** -- sent when the last pointer leaves the screen

now you can code according to above actions.